# RAW printing Central European characters

Tags: printing, zebra-printers

I'm developing a PHP/JavaScript application which should print receipts on Toshiba B-FV4 thermal printer using RAW printer commands (TPCL), using [QZ Tray](https://qz.io/). Everything works fine when printing Western Latin characters, but I'm unable to print Central European (ČĐŠ) or Cyrillic characters.

The command that I send to the printer is:

```
{PC016;0000,0550,05,05,A,00,B|}{RC016; Some čđš цбд text |}
```

The printer prints out only Western Latin characters, and skips the rest.

I've been looking all over the net for new printer firmware (and found nothing), tried to upload my fonts, and many other things, but without success.

Does anyone know how to add Central European characters to Toshiba thermal printers? How to upload .ttf font? Or is there a way to create your own font programmatically?

Answer (score -1):

There is library called [WebClientPrint](http://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/php/) for php language:

> WebClientPrint for PHP is a lightweight and plugin-free solution for Client-side Raw Printing scenarios for Windows, Linux & Mac clients, exclusively designed for PHP website projects. With our WebClientPrint solution, you can easily send raw data, text and native commands to printers installed at the client machine without showing or displaying any print dialog box!

Comment: This does not answer the question.